# Combining hashrouting and non hash routes in react not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have the following:

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/">
                        <HashRouter>
                            <Switch>
                                <Route exact path="/" component={ServiceHomepage}/>
                                <Rout path="/foo" component={FooPage}/>
                            </Switch>
                        </HashRouter>
                    </Route>
                    <Route exact path="/token_exchange" component={TokenExchange}/>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And I would expect so that if I were to hit `/` I should get the home page if I hit `/#/foo` I should get the FooPage, but for some reasons `/token_exchange` doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error I get:

`Cannot GET /token_exchange`

Comment: "/foo" isn't the same as "/#foo", the former is the `FooPage` while the latter would be a link into the `ServiceHomepage`. Check out [react-router-hash-link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link). If you want to hit an anchor tag on the foo page then the link would look like "/foo#foo".

Comment: Apologies, left out a `/`

Comment: Don't include the "/#" in your in-app links. If you want to link to the `FooPage` the path is "/foo". Also, why are you mixing and rendering more than 1 router?

Comment: the issue I'm running into is the token_exchange endpoint, that endpoint doesn't appear to be reachable @DrewReese

Comment: That should work, I don't see why it wouldn't other than maybe the path isn't exactly `"/token_exchange"`. If anything, the "/foo" route should be unreachable since the `exact path="/"` on the route rendering it precludes it as a match.

Comment: Hmm genuinely confused as to why it's not working. `/foo` doesn't work but `/#/foo` works this is such an odd scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add `historyApiFallback: true` to my webpack config file.